# What does "meadow is calling" means in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the the following quotation, what does meadow is calling mean?

> " I could tell you more of the story. But the meadow is calling."

EDIT:: 
As some of the answers required extra context, here is the whole paragraph.

> This was the icing on the cake. She told me that no one can do that.
>   That anyone who tried alternative means always ended up having to come
>   back to her to have it cut out! Yikes! Finally, she said that she
>   would give me eight weeks to shrink the tumor then she would cut it
>   out. Ha! I have yet to have surgery. And I am alive and well. I could
>   tell you more of the story. But the meadow is calling.

Comment: You should provide more context.  And look up the meaning of "call".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The/my/etc. X is calling" is a commonly used metaphor, meaning the person speaking has a desire to go to X and where X is an inanimate object. They feel as if X is literally beckoning to them to come.

In your example the person speaking wants to go to an, I assume, previously mentioned meadow.

Another example that one might hear is "my bed is calling." Usually heard from someone who is quite tired.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what it means exactly without additional context. But when you say that something is calling you or just calling, it usually means that you've got some kind of work or task that needs to be taken care of and you have to go and do it. You can think of it as a person who is literally asking (calling) you to come over and take care of them. In your example, it sounds like the speaker has some work that he has to do possibly in the nearby meadow. It may be a task such as cutting or collecting hay, for example. That's all I can infer from that excerpt.

Example:

> I have to go now. The work is calling. Talk to you later.

Comment: I have added the complete paragraph

Comment: The paragraph doesn't tell us who is speaking; perhaps a farmer?

Comment: @Kate Bunting That's very likely.